# Error Invoke manual correspondence in the number of parameters

Tags: c#

I have an error:

> Invoke manual correspondence in the number of parameters

I need to set `Visibile = false`.

```
private  void messaging(byte[] message)
{
    this.Invoke(new ClientReceiveHandler(ThrdClientOnClientReceive));
}
private void ThrdClientOnClientReceive(byte[] message)
{
      //MessageBox.Show("Client Event Handler --> Message:" + message);
      Visible = false;
}
```

I use invoke because I have more than one thread.

My handler: It work when the server sends a message to the client.

```
public event ClientReceiveHandler ClientReceive;
public delegate void ClientReceiveHandler(byte[] message);
public Thread thrdClient;
```

Comment: Your invoked method expects to receive an array of bytes. You don't provide it when invoking

Comment: can you edit for me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A parameter is missing on the invoke method:

```
this.Invoke(new ClientReceiveHandler(ThrdClientOnClientReceive), message);
```